# Error when running phpize command

Tags: php, xdebug, php-extension, phpize

I'm trying to install `xdebug` extenssion from source but when I run the `phpize` command I get the following errors:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/phpize: line 61: grep: command not found
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/phpize: line 62: grep: command not found
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/phpize: line 63: grep: command not found
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:
Zend Module Api No:
Zend Extension Api No:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/phpize: line 145: mkdir: command not found
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/phpize: line 147: cp: command not found
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/phpize: line 148: cp: command not found
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/phpize: line 149: cat: command not found
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/phpize: line 199: touch: command not found
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/phpize: line 106: chmod: command not found
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/phpize: line 109: cat: command not found
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are those files in the correct directory? It is basically saying (php) commands needed are not found where "it" thinks they are.

Comment: what happens if you execute `grep` command ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you don't have defined "**/bin**" into your **PATH** environment variable.

Try to set this one before executing phpize again:

```
export PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH"
```